# How to get the results ordered alternating between the tables when they have combined using UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two table like this:

```
// colors           // numbers
+----+-------+      +----+--------+
| id | color |      | id | number |
+----+-------+      +----+--------+
| 1  | red   |      | 1  | zero   |
| 2  | blue  |      | 2  | one    | 
| 3  | green |      | 3  | two    |
+----+-------+      | 4  | four   |
                    | 5  | eight  |
                    +----+--------+
```

Also here is my query:

```
select * from colors
  union all
select * from numbers
```

Now, the result of above query is like this: first all rows from `colors` table and then all rows from `numbers` table. But I don't want that sorting. I want this result:

```
+----+-------+
| id | color |
+----+-------+
| 1  | red   |
| 1  | zero  |
| 2  | blue  |
| 2  | one   |
| 3  | green |
| 3  | two   |
| 4  | four  |
| 5  | eight |
+----+-------+
```

How can I use `order by` for sorting like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
... Order By 1,2
```

To order by `column #1`, and then `column #2`.

Comment: There is no error... order is not what I want .. . I feel you misunderstood my point, I want alternating *rows*, but you told about *columns*

Comment: The rows are ordered by column.  did you try it ?

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine for me...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS colors;

CREATE TABLE colors
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,color VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO colors VALUES
(1  ,'red'),
(2  ,'blue'),
(3  ,'green');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS numbers;

CREATE TABLE numbers
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,number VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES
(1  ,'zero'),
(2  ,'one'),
(3  ,'two'),
(4  ,'four'),
(5  ,'eight');

SELECT * FROM colors UNION ALL SELECT * FROM numbers ORDER BY id;
+----+-------+
| id | color |
+----+-------+
|  1 | red   |
|  1 | zero  |
|  2 | blue  |
|  2 | one   |
|  3 | green |
|  3 | two   |
|  4 | four  |
|  5 | eight |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: @Sajad Yes. The table doesn't exist.

Comment: doesn't exist?! what?? so what is this? `CREATE TABLE colors` and `CREATE TABLE numbers`